# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storages.backends.s3boto'

Tags: django, heroku, boto, django-storage

So, I have installed django storages and boto + boto3. They are in my requirements.txt and I made sure to install it while in my virtual environment. requirements is in my root obviously. Why am I still getting this error?

**requirements.txt**

```
beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.14.16
botocore==1.17.16
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.3
django-bootstrap4==1.1.1
django-storages==1.9.1
djangorestframework==3.10.2
docutils==0.15.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
jmespath==0.10.0
Markdown==3.1.1
pbr==5.4.5
Pillow==7.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
pygame==1.9.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.1
s3transfer==0.3.3
six==1.14.0
soupsieve==2.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
stevedore==1.32.0
urllib3==1.25.9
virtualenv==16.6.1
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.4
whitenoise==5.1.0
```

**settings.py**

```
import six
import os
from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage` you should use `from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage`